# Slow SQLite - How to boost performances?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using SQLite3 for react native https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-sqlite-2

```
CREATE TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS projects (
 id text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 name text NOT NULL,
 begin_date text,
 end_date text
)WITHOUT ROWID;
```

I have about 10k row and want select 100 row using the following query

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id IN ("id1","id2",...,"id100")
```

In android 7 phone with 8 core cpu and 8Gig RAM . the query take about 2 sec but when I run the query in desktop PC in same database it take only 80ms

How can I optimize in android??
I also remove `WITHOUT ROWID` clause for test

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-2';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('test.db', '1.0', '', 1);
db.transaction(function (txn) {
  txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id IN ("id1","id2",...,"id100")', [], function (tx, res) {
    for (let i = 0; i < res.rows.length; ++i) {
      console.log('item:', res.rows.item(i));
    }
  });
});
```

executeSql takes about 2 sec (Don't include open db and transaction)

Comment: Show the code that reads the rows.

Comment: **Index** the *WHERE* fields. And... why are your id fields **strings**?! This would **slow down** quite a lot, respect to **integer** fields.

Comment: Index primary key??? Why??  I have to have Text primary key. Why the query is fast in PC?

Comment: @CL. JS code added

Comment: How fast does it run without the `log`?

Comment: No different without log